# bugzilla: install-module.pl GD return shows an error

Tags: mysql, mamp, cpan, bugzilla

Trying to setup bugzilla on mac. trying to install DBD mysql but get the following error back:

```
> enter code hereChecking if your kit is complete... Looks good Warning
> (mostly harmless): No library found for -lmysqlclient Using DBI 1.631
> (for perl 5.018002 on darwin-thread-multi-2level) installed in
> /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/
> Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json cp
> lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm cp
> lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod blib/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod cp
> lib/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql.pm cp lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
> blib/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm cp README.pod blib/lib/DBD/README.pod cc
> -c  -I/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -g -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -Os   -DVERSION=\"4.032\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.032\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  
> dbdimp.c In file included from dbdimp.c:20: ./dbdimp.h:21:10: fatal
> error: 'mysql.h' file not found
> #include <mysql.h>  /* Comes with MySQL-devel */
>          ^ 1 error generated. make: *** [dbdimp.o] Error 1   CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.032.tar.gz   /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK Skipping
> test because of notest pragma Running make install   Make had returned
> bad status, install seems impossible
```

Cant proceed any further with the setup

Answer (score 2):

It's looking for the header files and libraries for MySQL, which are an external dependencies for DBD::mysql. You either need to install the MySQL, the MySQL client libraries, or tell the installer where you installed those.

Comment: You can install those libraries using homebrew: `brew install mysql-connector-c`